# Pyspark partitionBy, groupBy, for data filtering

Tags: python, pyspark

assume you have a (big) dataset, a portion of which might look like this (in the real dataset there are more columns).

```
+---+-----+---------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|   |  i  |    B    |    C     |     D     |       E        |
+---+-----+---------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|   | .   | House A | Garden X | Terrace C | 90             |
|   | .   | House A | Garden X | Terrace C | 80             |
|   | .   | House A | Garden X | Terrace D | 60             |
|   | .   | House B | Garden X | Terrace E | 75             |
|   | .   | House C | Garden Z | Terrace C | 85             |
+---+-----+---------+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

I want to use pyspark to filter the data by B, C and D, such that I can compute statistics on E.

For example, grouping under 'House A' will eventually yield the following two partitions:

```
+---+-----+---------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|   |  i  |    B    |    C     |     D     |       E        |
+---+-----+---------+----------+-----------+----------------+
|   | .   | House A | Garden X | Terrace C | 90             |
|   | .   | House A | Garden X | Terrace C | 80             |
```

and

```
|   | .   | House A | Garden X | Terrace D | 60             |
```

Effectively, I want to filter subsets of data with unique characteristics.

I am very confused about how to manage this with PySpark. I played around with groupBy and partitionBy functions, but I cannot get past the first 'filtering' operation, that is - for example - producing a subtable for 'House A'. I have been told to look into the 'window' functions of PySpark, but I have seen it mostly being applied to the problem of doing computations within consecutive rows of a given table.

Note: I do not want to store the filtered data-tables.
I just want to compute a summary statistic, which could be the mean of the values of E.

Any help appreciated.

SC

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you just want do perform a `group by` operation.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy("B", "C", "D").agg(F.avg("E"))
```